# Calculate Limit of Lebesgue Integral: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^1_0 \frac{1}{1+\cos^{2n}(x+n)} d\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Calculate:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^1_0 \frac{1}{1+\cos^{2n}(x+n)} d\lambda$$

My idea was to use dominated convergence theorem - since $0 \leq \cos^{2n}(x+n)\leq 1$, we can have the bound $ |\frac{1}{1+\cos^{2n}(x+n)}| \leq 1 < \infty $. Thus we can apply dominated convergence theorem and pull the limit into the integral. However, I think the limit of the cosine term diverges so this method doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Note that $\cos^{2}(x+n)< 1$ for almost every $x \in (0,1)$, and therefore when you take the $n$ power and compute the limit, this function goes pointwise to $0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: How does $x$ relate to $\lambda$?

Comment: @MarkViola $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Jotabeta thank you!

Comment: @MarkViola This is how the exercise is written. Maybe to emphasize that its a lebesgue integral and that the riemann integral may not exist for sure?

Comment: That might be correct.